# Can't display boostrap modal, only backdrop

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Basically i'm trying to call a modal after login success, here's the code:

```
<div id="modalOpt" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog-OptIn">
        <div class="modal-content-OptIn">
            <div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body-text">
                <p class="title-text">Autorização de envio de agenda</p>
                <p class="subTitle">Autorizo as instituições x1 e x2 a
                     consultarem toda a minha agenda de recebíveis na Única. </p>
                <p class="subTitle">Autorizando, você terá os seguintes benefícios:</p>
                <ul class="bullet">
                    <li class="bulletItems">Operações e produtos pré-aprovados</li>
                    <li class="bulletItems">Melhores negociações de taxas</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="row-modal">
                    <button class="btnOptIn-1" data-target="#success" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Permitir
                    </button>
                    <button class="btnOptIn-2" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Decidir depois                  
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling this modal inside login.js, like this:

```
const onEventSuccessLogin = () => {
        onNavegarDashboard();
        $('#modalOpt').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true});
    }
```

But for some reason, the modal itself doesn't appear, only modal-backdrop, i've already tried to change z-index, but it doesn't work.

The only way i managed to show the modal is to put the html inside index.html, but once i do this, and i go back (in browser) to the login page, the html stands fixed in the screen for some reason.

After all, i wanted to fix this bug so i put the html inside login.html, then i got this problem with modal-backdrop and the modal not being called.

Any suggestions?

Here's an screenshot to clarify:

[image: modal not being called, only modal backdrop]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your first line from

```
<div id="modalOpt" class="modal" role="dialog">
```

to

```
 <div id="modalOpt" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
```

Alternatively, just add a class "fade in" to your initial modal class, not so sure why that happens.